# How to specify the constructor to use in json configuration

Tags: constructor, configuration, dependencies, autofac

I'm trying to specifiy the constructor to use in autofac json configuration file.

By code a can use the `UsingConstructor(...)` method.

I tried different configuration but no one works.

Example of my tests :

    `{
          "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.PubSub.Producer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging",
          "services": [
            {
              "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IProducer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction",
              "constructor": "System.String, System.Guid, System.String, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IAmqpConnectionFactory"
            }
          ]
        }`

`{
          "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.PubSub.Producer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging",
          "services": [
            {
              "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IProducer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction",
              "using-constructor": "System.String, System.Guid, System.String, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IAmqpConnectionFactory"
            }
          ]
        }`

`{
      "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.PubSub.Producer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IProducer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction"
        }
      ],
      "using-constructor": "System.String, System.Guid, System.String, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IAmqpConnectionFactory"
    }`

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

JSON configuration doesn't support specifying constructor. Config isn't a feature for feature replacement for code based setup. [See documentation here.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html)

Comment: Hummmm it's really a problem for me. I will try to implement it!

Comment: Read the docs and look at modules. Programmatically set it up in a module, register the module with config.

Comment: I just extend the ComponentRegistrar class, and add a method that support the usage of constructor specification in config file.     `{
      "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.PubSub.Producer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging",
      "constructor": [ "System.String", "System.Guid", "System.String", "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IAmqpConnectionFactory, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction" ],
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction.IProducer, BlueCurve.Search.Messaging.Abstraction"
        }
      ]
    }`